# Forever node process set to restart via crontab NOT restarting

Tags: node.js, cron, forever

If I run **start_test.sh** (as root) from the command line it restarts fine. However if I try to have it run via **crontab** it does not restart the forever process and I have no helpful output as to why this is the case.

**sudo crontab -e**

```
SHELL=/bin/sh PATH=/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin

29 14 * * * /var/local/node_test/start_test.sh
```

**start_test.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
forever --killSignal=SIGINT restart -c /usr/local/bin/node /var/local/node_test/server.js
```

**/var/log/syslog at 14:29**

```
Mar 18 14:29:01 app-srv CRON[4394]: (root) CMD (/var/local/node_test/start_test.sh)
```

Comment: Do you run the `start_test.sh` as root since it looks like crontab is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could save yourself some time by using [pm2](https://github.com/Unitech/PM2) tool. It can [restart a process](https://github.com/Unitech/PM2/blob/development/ADVANCED_README.md#json-app-declaration) for you automatically.

Install pm2:

```
sudo npm i pm2 -g
```

Create a `processes.json` somewhere.

```
[{
  "name": "server",
  "cwd" : "/var/local/node_test/",
  "cron_restart" : "1 0 * * *"
}]
```

Start the process(es) with:

```
pm2 startOrRestart processes.json
```

The tool can do much more for you. Like restarting a process when it takes too much memory or setting environment variables for your process. Just browse the [readme](https://github.com/Unitech/PM2/blob/development/ADVANCED_README.md).